# Protractor - Unable to loop every item by using ElemArrayFinder each

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using Protractor + Jasmine.

I have 2 elements (links) in a table, and I need to delete one after one - Or one-by-one. After I deleted the first item, the table will refresh and re-populated with the remaining elements (or links).

My code below only deleting the first element and exiting the code. I am unable to loop and delete all elements.

I am getting the total count correct.

```
element.all(by.xpath("//span[@class='abc']")).count().then(function (count) 
    {
      element.all(by.xpath("//span[@class='abc']")).each(function (elem, index)
       { 
          elem.getText().then(function (name) 
          {
          console.log("NAME IS " + name);
          var row = element(by.xpath('//span[contains(text(),"' + name + '")]/../../..'));
          row.click();
          var overFlow = element(by.xpath('//span[contains(text(),"' + name + '")]/../../..//*[@class="zzz"]'));
          helper.clickElemWithJavascript(overFlow);
          helper.scrollIntoView(deleteButton);
          helper.clickElemWithJavascript(deleteButton); 
        })
      }) 
    }); //count
```

Comment: could you add what error do you get? I suppose it is Stale Reference error.

Comment: Please show your table HTML code

Comment: @OleksiiI  - I figured it out. I used to get stale element issue.

Comment: @Yong - Thanks for trying to help me out. I am posting my answer below/

Answer (score 0):

Promises chaining is one solution for this kind of issues.

I figured it out in this way and this is my approach:

1. I made these steps as a function.
2. I get the total count of elements using element.all().each(). This returns array of elements/array of values.
3. Using a For loop and length of the above array, calling the function (step 1) which has steps to delete Single element.
4. I followed Promises chaining. So unless the previous step was not finished, control flow will not execute the next step.
5. I am not familiar with Async and Await, so I followed the approach above.